# How to scan/load all the files from Internal and External storage in android 10 and android 11

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

In android 10 and in android 11 how to load all files from internal and external storage. Actually I want to load a specific extension files (i.e.pdf, txt) within my app, either the specific extension file is saved in internal or external storage.

I have used the following code which is working fine upto android 8.1 API Level 26

I have taken the StorageUtil class from internet, which will load all the possible physical path

```
public class StorageUtil {

    // Primary physical SD-CARD (not emulated)
    private static final String EXTERNAL_STORAGE = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE");

    // All Secondary SD-CARDs (all exclude primary) separated by File.pathSeparator, i.e: ":", ";"
    private static final String SECONDARY_STORAGES = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");

    // Primary emulated SD-CARD
    private static final String EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET = System.getenv("EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET");

    // PhysicalPaths based on phone model
    @SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
    @SuppressWarnings("SpellCheckingInspection")
    private static final String[] KNOWN_PHYSICAL_PATHS = new String[]{
            "/storage/sdcard0",
            "/storage/sdcard1",                 //Motorola Xoom
            "/storage/extsdcard",               //Samsung SGS3
            "/storage/sdcard0/external_sdcard", //User request
            "/mnt/extsdcard",
            "/mnt/sdcard/external_sd",          //Samsung galaxy family
            "/mnt/sdcard/ext_sd",
            "/mnt/external_sd",
            "/mnt/media_rw/sdcard1",            //4.4.2 on CyanogenMod S3
            "/removable/microsd",               //Asus transformer prime
            "/mnt/emmc",
            "/storage/external_SD",             //LG
            "/storage/ext_sd",                  //HTC One Max
            "/storage/removable/sdcard1",       //Sony Xperia Z1
            "/data/sdext",
            "/data/sdext2",
            "/data/sdext3",
            "/data/sdext4",
            "/sdcard1",                         //Sony Xperia Z
            "/sdcard2",                         //HTC One M8s
            "/storage/microsd"                  //ASUS ZenFone 2
    };

    /**
     * Returns all available storages in the system (include emulated)
     * <p/>
     * Warning: Hack! Based on Android source code of version 4.3 (API 18)
     * Because there is no standard way to get it.
     *
     * @return paths to all available storages in the system (include emulated)
     */
    public static String[] getStorageDirectories(Context context) {
        // Final set of paths
        final Set<String> availableDirectoriesSet = new HashSet<>();

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET)) {
            // Device has an emulated storage
            availableDirectoriesSet.add(getEmulatedStorageTarget());
        } else {
            // Device doesn't have an emulated storage
            availableDirectoriesSet.addAll(getExternalStorage(context));
        }

        // Add all secondary storages
        Collections.addAll(availableDirectoriesSet, getAllSecondaryStorages());

        String[] storagesArray = new String[availableDirectoriesSet.size()];
        return availableDirectoriesSet.toArray(storagesArray);
    }

    private static Set<String> getExternalStorage(Context context) {
        final Set<String> availableDirectoriesSet = new HashSet<>();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            // Solution of empty raw emulated storage for android version >= marshmallow
            // because the EXTERNAL_STORAGE become something like: "/Storage/A5F9-15F4",
            // so we can't access it directly
            File[] files = getExternalFilesDirs(context, null);
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file != null) {
                    String applicationSpecificAbsolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                    String rootPath = applicationSpecificAbsolutePath.substring(
                            0,
                            applicationSpecificAbsolutePath.indexOf("Android/data")
                    );
                    availableDirectoriesSet.add(rootPath);
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                availableDirectoriesSet.addAll(getAvailablePhysicalPaths());
            } else {
                // Device has physical external storage; use plain paths.
                availableDirectoriesSet.add(EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
        }
        return availableDirectoriesSet;
    }

    private static String getEmulatedStorageTarget() {
        String rawStorageId = "";
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            // External storage paths should have storageId in the last segment
            // i.e: "/storage/emulated/storageId" where storageId is 0, 1, 2, ...
            final String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            final String[] folders = path.split(File.separator);
            final String lastSegment = folders[folders.length - 1];
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(lastSegment) && TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(lastSegment)) {
                rawStorageId = lastSegment;
            }
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(rawStorageId)) {
            return EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET;
        } else {
            return EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET + File.separator + rawStorageId;
        }
    }

    private static String[] getAllSecondaryStorages() {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(SECONDARY_STORAGES)) {
            // All Secondary SD-CARDs split into array
            return SECONDARY_STORAGES.split(File.pathSeparator);
        }
        return new String[0];
    }

    /**
     * Filter available physical paths from known physical paths
     *
     * @return List of available physical paths from current device
     */
    private static List<String> getAvailablePhysicalPaths() {
        List<String> availablePhysicalPaths = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String physicalPath : KNOWN_PHYSICAL_PATHS) {
            File file = new File(physicalPath);
            if (file.exists()) {
                availablePhysicalPaths.add(physicalPath);
            }
        }
        return availablePhysicalPaths;
    }

    /**
     * Returns absolute paths to application-specific directories on all
     * external storage devices where the application can place persistent files
     * it owns. These files are internal to the application, and not typically
     * visible to the user as media.
     * <p>
     * This is like {@link Context#getFilesDir()} in that these files will be
     * deleted when the application is uninstalled, however there are some
     * important differences:
     * <ul>
     * <li>External files are not always available: they will disappear if the
     * user mounts the external storage on a computer or removes it.
     * <li>There is no security enforced with these files.
     * </ul>
     * <p>
     * External storage devices returned here are considered a permanent part of
     * the device, including both emulated external storage and physical media
     * slots, such as SD cards in a battery compartment. The returned paths do
     * not include transient devices, such as USB flash drives.
     * <p>
     * An application may store data on any or all of the returned devices. For
     * example, an app may choose to store large files on the device with the
     * most available space, as measured by {@link android.os.StatFs}.
     * <p>
     * Starting in {@link Build.VERSION_CODES#KITKAT}, no permissions
     * are required to write to the returned paths; they're always accessible to
     * the calling app. Before then,
     * {@link android.Manifest.permission#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE} is required to
     * write. Write access outside of these paths on secondary external storage
     * devices is not available. To request external storage access in a
     * backwards compatible way, consider using {@code android:maxSdkVersion}
     * like this:
     *
     * <pre class="prettyprint">&lt;uses-permission
     *     android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
     *     android:maxSdkVersion="18" /&gt;</pre>
     * <p>
     * The first path returned is the same as
     * {@link Context#getExternalFilesDir(String)}. Returned paths may be
     * {@code null} if a storage device is unavailable.
     *
     * @see Context#getExternalFilesDir(String)
     */
    private static File[] getExternalFilesDirs(Context context, String type) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            return context.getExternalFilesDirs(type);
        } else {
            return new File[]{context.getExternalFilesDir(type)};
        }
    }
```

And loadDirectoryFiles function which will load all the files within specific directory

```
    object LoadDirectory {
    
        fun loadDirectoryFiles(directory: File) {
            try {
                val fileList: Array<File> = directory.listFiles()
                if (fileList.isNotEmpty()) {
                    for (i in fileList.indices) {
                        if (fileList[i].isDirectory) {
                            loadDirectoryFiles(fileList[i])
                        } else {
                            val name: String = fileList[i].name.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                            //Now look for desired extension
                            if (name.endsWith(Constants.PDF_EXTENSION)) {
                                Constants.allFileList.add(fileList[i])
                            }
    
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (e : Exception){
                Log.d("TAG","Error: ${e.message} and directory: ${directory.absoluteFile}")
            }
        }
    }
```

and here its usage

```
  val storagePaths = StorageUtil.getStorageDirectories(this)
    
   for (path in storagePaths) {
       val storageFile = File(path)
       LoadDirectory.loadDirectoryFiles(storageFile)
   }
```

The above code is working fine upto android 8.1 but is not working on above android 8.1, Now how to achieve this by loading a specific extension (i.e. pdf) files from internal and external storage

Thanks in advance for helping me

Comment: You are doing nothing with files with a specific extension so i think you can continue to do nothing on 10 and 11. Please reformulate your problem.

Comment: `final String[] KNOWN_PHYSICAL_PATHS` That is a ridiculous array. You better do away with it also for below 10. Things can be done differently.

Comment: Use the second item returned by getExternalFilesDirs() to get a path to a removable micro sd card.

Comment: `load all files` ? Load? What do you mean with load? You are not loading anything as far as i can see.

Comment: `have taken the StorageUtil class from internet` It would have been better if you had never found that class. As all that you need is getExternalStorageDirectory() and getExternalFilesDirs().

Comment: Okay i'll try this getExternalStorageDirectory() and getExternalFilesDirs(),Thanks, load all files ? Load? What do you mean with load? "i'm filtering all pdf files and saving it into arraylist"

Comment: Try those functions first on devices with Android version not Q. As with Q things are picky a bit. Above Q is ok again.

Comment: getExternalStorageDirectory() and getExternalFilesDirs(), actually it is not solving my problem, i want to get all pdf files whether it is in external or internal storage or pdf file is private to an app

Comment: You can have files private for your app in getFilesDir(). But that path is not im your old list. So how could you not find a pdf now? Those three functions cover all there is. If you think something is missing (which is not the case) then tell full path.

Comment: getFilesDir(),getExternalStorageDirectory() and getExternalFilesDirs() all these is working fine on android 8.1 but is not working on android 10 (api 29) and android 11 (api 30)

Comment: They give nice full paths on Android 10 and 11 devices too. So they work i would say. They work on all Android versions. But as said before do not test on an Android 10 device now. Keep that for later when your new code works. Use an Android 11 emulator and see that you can recursively list all wanted files.

Comment: If you want to work with some special files, why don't you use `ContentProvider`?

Comment: How to get Real path from URI in android 11, the uri will be like that content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/16, sorry for the irrelevant comment